# Authorization don't pass in request AngularJs/PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, jwt

I'm implementing a JWT authentification and I got a problem with the authorization set in the header.

It's looking like the 'Authorization' header isn't set in the request.

I got 2 request send by the client, the first one, the Authorization header pass in the request :

```
// GET PROJECTS NAME
projects.getName = () => {  // === projects.getName = function() { ... }
return $http.get(Global.url_api+'action=GETINFO&table=Projects');
}
```

Request in  browser :

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi....
Host: *******-tpinst.fr
Origin: http://localhost:2000
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost:2000/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

But my second request implemented as the same as the first one didn't pass this authorization header :

```
users.get = function(project){
return $http.get(Global.url_api+'action=GET&table='+project+'_users');
}
```

In the browser :

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Host: bouygues-tpinst.fr
Origin: http://localhost:2000
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
```

The authorization is set in main program :

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer 
'+localStorage.getItem('tokenAPI');
}])
```

I set Allow origin in my server side with these lines :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, 
OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
```

I'm a beginner in these security notions, please guide me on a good way

**EDIT :**

I just found a hint, in my api.php i got this line to send error 401 to client :

```
$Authorization = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];

//Looking for authorization headers
if($Authorization){ ... }
else {  
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized'); //Give error code 401
    echo 'Token not found in the header';
}
```

When i delete

> header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

The Authorization pass in the header

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common`

instead implement an http interceptor

Try this

```
app.factory("authInterceptor", authInterceptor);

authInterceptor.$inject = ["$q"];

function authInterceptor($q) {
    return {

        // Add an interceptor for requests.
        'request': function (config) {
            // Default to an empty object if no headers are set.
            config.headers = config.headers || {}; 
            // Set the token
            var token = localStorage.getItem('tokenAPI');
            config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;

            return config;
        },

        // Add an interceptor for any responses that error.
        'responseError': function (response) {

            // Check if the error is auth-related.
            if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {

            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }

    };

}


app.config(["$httpProvider",
    function ($httpProvider) {
        //Registers the interceptor
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push("authInterceptor");
    }]);
```

And i think the re-arrangement of your scripts causes the issue, place your controller script in the bottom

something like this

[image]

And in your **main.js** remove the 
`var app = angular.module('App', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])` because we placed it in the `index.html`

Comment: First, thanks for take the time to reply @John. I've tryed your solution but i'm not pretty sure how to call this factory. I created a new file called "authInterceptor" and paste this code. And in my main controller , i added "authInterceptor" in constructor and now got a wicked error in my console :  `Error: [$injector:unpr]`. Here is how i called this factory : `app.controller('Ctrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope','$http','$timeout','$mdDialog','authInterceptor',... function($rootScope, $scope, $http){...}`

Comment: no, don't add it to the controller, just leave it there, the only use for `authInterceptor` is to intercept incoming request, meaning all your request will be bound there first.

Comment: It's the same problem, first request send authorization but not the second.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking time for me. Here is the plunker : [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/YmN5wmpjbX8UmxgYdAwg?p=preview) , the first request is on projects.js l.6 , the second is on user.js l.5, i just copy/paste what it should be interresting, if you need more, ask me.

Comment: Your plunk is empty, please check again

Comment: [Edited plunk](http://embed.plnkr.co/YmN5wmpjbX8UmxgYdAwg/)  It should be fine. Sorry i'm not sure how to share the URL.

Comment: Your plunker has many errors, currently what is the error of your console?